# PHP: How to get all substrings that occur a specific number of times in a string

Tags: php, substring

In php what function can I use to get a return of all substrings that appear >=13 times in a string? Can you provide example of how to use it?
Cheers.

Example:
I have a substring such as "rain in the same place, rain in the new place, rain in the old place". I would like to print out all of the substrings that appear 3 or more times in the string. The answer would give an array of array(rain, in, the, place)

Comment: what have you tried to do, can you add your trial code, so we can pick it up from there

Comment: @Theophilus-Omoregbee I have not been able to find a single starting example for something like that, I found something using array_filter on arrays but nothing for strings. I am starting to believe it is not possible but I decided to ask the experts.

Comment: ok can you still give a logical example of what you are trying to say in your question

Comment: Is it impossible in php? Is there no function for it? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for substrings but your examples show that you want words:

```php
$words = str_word_count($string, 1);

$frequency = array_count_values($words);

$result = array_filter($frequency, function ($x) { return $x >= 13; });
```

For non-English and non-Spanish languages you have to pass a string that contains all characters from desired language as a 3rd param to the `str_word_count` method.

Also I don't know why have you asked an array of array.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Appreciate it. Ran your code with my string but got back a null array. Dreamweaver is picking up an error at the line below:
$result = array_filter($frequency, function ($x) { return $x >= 13; });
Same error I keep getting from examples in the php manual but can't figure out how to correct it.

Comment: @user3152377 what PHP version do you use and may you share your string example? Example above use anonymous function and if your PHP is old and does not support it you are able to move ```function ($x) { return $x >= 13; }``` into the function ```function example($x) { return $x >= 13; }``` and use ```array_filter($frequency, 'example')``` to use this function with it's name only.

Comment: @user3152377 and if you see the error only in Dreamweaver (editor, not PHP interpreter itself), try to find the settings and check does it has any dropdown with PHP version. Looks like your editor tries to validate your code for PHP v5.2 or even older.

Comment: Thanks! I was incorrect, your code was right, I was using numbers in the string and did not realize that these needed to be notated to the statement. Like I did below:
$somearray = str_word_count($resultround, 1, '1234567890:@&_');